# create step spark python, amazon hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am creating a Spark step with Hadoop on Amazon, but I left thinking all the time. Not if it's because I'm bad code or sending bad judgment, but can not find a way out.

I pass code

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 1g s3://URL-S3/scripts/test.py
```

Script:

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('TestSpark')

table.put_item(
   Item={
        'app_token': "1a",
        'advertising_id': "1b",
    }
)
```

I returned all the time

```
16/08/25 07:06:22 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:23 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:24 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:25 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:26 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:27 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:28 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:29 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:30 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:31 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:32 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:33 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:34 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:35 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:36 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:37 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:38 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:39 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:40 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:41 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/25 07:06:42 INFO Client: Application report for application_1472106590712_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

Error Log:

```
2016-08-25T07:30:14.769Z INFO Step created jobs: 
2016-08-25T07:30:14.769Z WARN Step failed with exitCode 1 and took 1062 seconds
```

Thx!

Which it is already the error, but the module and install it before.

> ImportError: No module named boto3

Comment: Have you read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-4.7.2/emr-spark-submit-step.html? I've never worked with Spark steps, but after skimming over the doc it seems that it's not you to `spark-submit` but the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And locate the error.

Boto3 module was not installed, install it from console, but the steps do not work, because they would have to install it in all instances. So what I did was create another claster running a boostrap-action update python I installed the module boto3

Answer (score 1):

You application is waiting for yarn resources. Goto resource manager URL and see if you enough resources and using right queue. If you look at yarn resourcemanager logs will know the reason.

Comment: shows this error:

2016-08-25T07:30:14.769Z INFO Step created jobs: 
2016-08-25T07:30:14.769Z WARN Step failed with exitCode 1 and took 1062 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I don't work on Amazon EMR, but in Hadoop this happens when your YARN is waiting for resources for too long.

The resource negotiator couldn't allocate the required resources, try to reduce the resources required by your code. Also check the logs.

Read through: [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/running-on-yarn.html)

Also check the status of YARN,

```
sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager status
sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager status
```